# Tengo un problema con mi boton de editar

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, crud

Ya tengo todo solo me falta el boton de editar pero no se edita, les paso el HTML y el php.

```html
<?php include('php/registrar.php');
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
      $id=$_GET['edit'];
      $editar_estado=true;
      $rec=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tarjetas WHERE id=$id");
      $record=mysqli_fetch_array($rec);
      $nombre=$record['nombre'];
      $apellido=$record['apellido'];
      $correo=$record['correo'];
      $clave=$record['clave'];
      $telefono=$record['telefono'];
      $id=$record['id'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Estilos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/avisos.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])):?>
<div class="msg">
  <?php
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
   ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
    <h1>Plantilla</h1>
    <form action="php/registrar.php" method="post" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar();">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <h2 class="form_titulo">Introduzca sus datos</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
      <input type="text"     name="nombre"     id="nombre"      placeholder="Nombre"       class="input-100" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" >
      <input type="text"     name="apellido"   id="apellido"    placeholder="Apellido"     class="input-100" value="<?php echo $apellido; ?>" >
      <input type="email"    name="correo"     id="correo"      placeholder="Correo"       class="input-100" value="<?php echo $correo; ?>">
      <input type="password" name="clave"      id="clave"       placeholder="clave"        class="input-100" value="<?php echo $clave; ?>" >
      <input type="tel"      name="telefono"   id="telefono"    placeholder="Telefono"     class="input-100" value="<?php echo $telefono; ?>">
    <!-- <input type="submit"   name="enviar"  id="enviar"   value="Enviar"   class="btn_enviar" >-->
<?php  if ($editar_estado == false): ?>
  <button type="submit" name="btn_enviar" class="btn_enviar">Enviar</button>
<?php else : ?>
  <button type="submit" name="btn_actualizar" class="btn_actualizar">Actualizar</button>
<?php endif ?>
    </div>
    </form>

    <!--Tablas-->
    <div class="contenedor">
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>clave</th>
        <th>telefono</th>
        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["id"];       ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["nombre"];   ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["apellido"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["correo"];   ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["clave"];    ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["telefono"]; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn_editar"   href="Index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >Editar</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn_eliminar" href="php/registrar.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Eliminar</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script type="js/validar.js"></script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Creo que esta mal mi sentencia de SQL y si pueden darme consejos de Injection SQL

```html
<?php
session_start();

//variables
$nombre="";
$apellido="";
$correo="";
$clave="";
$telefono="";
$id=0;
$editar_estado=false;

//conexion
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','koUeARe1bX4YlfrE','plantilla');

//Boton Enviar
  if (isset($_POST['btn_enviar'])) {
  $nombre=  $_POST["nombre"];
  $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
  $correo=  $_POST["correo"];
  $clave=   $_POST["clave"];
  $telefono=$_POST["telefono"];

//Consulta para guardar
  $insertar ="INSERT INTO tarjetas(nombre, apellido, correo, clave, telefono)
  VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$clave','$telefono');";
  $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
  $_SESSION['msg']="Usuario guardado";
  header('Location:../Index.php');
}

//Boton Actualizar
if (isset($_POST['btn_actualizar'])) {
  $nombre  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
  $apellido= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['apellido']);
  $correo  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['correo']);
  $clave   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['clave']);
  $telefono= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['telefono']);
  $id      = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

  mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE tarjetas SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido', correo='$correo', clave='$clave', telefono='$telefono' WHERE id='$id'");
  $_SESSION['msg']="Usuario actualizado";
  header('location:../Index.php');
}
//boton de borrar
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
  $id=$_GET['del'];
  mysqli_query($conexion,"DELETE FROM  tarjetas WHERE id=$id");
  $_SESSION['msg']="Usuario borrado";
  header('location:../Index.php');
}


//registrar informacion
$mostrar ="SELECT * FROM tarjetas;";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$mostrar)
//cerrar conexion

 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?  ¿Verificaste que los nombres de tabla y columnas están bien escritos? ¿Verificaste que los valores de las variables son todos correctos? ¿De qué tipo es la columna `id` en tu tabla `tarjetas`?  ¿No será que el `UPDATE` crearía un valor duplicado y por eso falla? ¿O que una de las variables es `NULL` para una columna que no admite nulos? Cuando dilucidemos esas dudas y funcione entonces podremos hablar sobre la inyección SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto para la función de actualizar.

Te comento brevemente en qué consiste mi propuesta:

- Se trata de un código controlado, que va recogiendo en la variable `$arrStatus` todo lo que ocurra, éxitos o errores del código.
- Para recoger los valores del POST usaremos operadores ternarios, preguntando si ese valor no está vacío. Si lo está, le asignamos `NULL`. A mi me gusta esta forma, porque luego podemos restringir la consulta. Por ejemplo, si las *columnas esenciales*  vienen nulas, paramos el intento de `UPDATE`, dado que no podemos permitir que esa columnas de guarden con valores nulos. Se supone que, por otra parte, esas columnas tendrás la restricción  `NOT NULL` en la base de datos. Aquí yo he asumido que son tres esas columnas *esenciales*. Eso lo puedes cambiar según tu diseño.
- Prescindiremos de `mysqli_real_escape_string`, pues vamos a usar consultas preparadas. Es la mejor medida para proteger el código de inyección SQL.
- En la fase de la consulta preparada, mucha atención a la función `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`... allí he asumido que todas las columnas que participan son alfanuméricas, excepto la última, que es `id`... por eso al final hay una `i`. Si el `id` es alfanumérico, debes cambiar la `i` por una `s`.
- El código controla todos los puntos neurálgicos de la preparación y que pueden fallar, recogiendo los mensajes de error de esos fallos.
- El código no muestra inocentemente que hubo una actualización. Eso solamente puede determinarse si hubieron filas afectadas.
- Al final de todo se verifica la clave `status` de nuestro array utilitario y solamente si es `TRUE` se actualiza la variable de sesión y se hace la redirección. Esa parte la puedes cambiar a tu gusto. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer la redirección igual, pero informando correctamente sobre lo que ha ocurrido. Pues como ves, pueden ocurrir mil motivos para que la actualización no ocurra. Y esto con o sin errores. Imaginemos que la condición del `WHERE` no se cumple. En ese caso no habrá ninguna actualización. Todo eso debe ser controlado en el código.

La propuesta, una vez indicado todo lo anterior, sería esta:

```
$arrStatus=array();
if (isset($_POST['btn_actualizar'])) {
    /*Usamos operadores ternarios para guardar los valores del POST*/
    $nombre     = (empty($_POST['nombre'])) NULL ? $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido   = (empty($_POST['apellido'])) NULL ? $_POST['apellido'];
    $correo     = (empty($_POST['correo'])) NULL ? $_POST['correo'];
    $clave      = (empty($_POST['clave'])) NULL ? $_POST['clave'];
    $telefono   = (empty($_POST['telefono'])) NULL ? $_POST['telefono'];
    $id         = (empty($_POST['id'])) NULL ? $_POST['id'];

  /*
        *Bloqueamos si algún valor esencial es NULL
        *aquí supongo que id, nombre y apellido no pueden ser nulos
        *si hay más los agregas a la condición
  */

    if ($nombre && $apellido && $id){
        $sql="UPDATE tarjetas SET nombre=?, apellido=?, correo=?, clave=?, telefono=? WHERE id=?";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql)){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssi", $nombre,$apellido,$correo,$clave,$telefono,$id);
                if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    $totalFilas=mysqli_affected_rows($conexion);
                    if($totalFilas>0)
                        $arrStatus=array("status"=>TRUE, "msg"=>"Se actualizaron $totalFilas filas");
                    }else{
                        $arrStatus=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"Ninguna fila actualizada");
                    }
                 }else{
                    $msg="La actualización falló: ".mysqli_error($conexion);    
                    $arrStatus=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"$msg");
                }
        }else{
              $msg="La preparación falló: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
              $arrStatus=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"$msg");               
        }     
    }else{
          $arrStatus=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"Hay datos esenciales que son nulos o están en blanco");

    }
    /*Verificamos el estado del array*/ 
    if ($arrStatus["status"]==TRUE){
        $_SESSION['msg']="Usuario actualizado";
        header('location:../Index.php');
    }else{
        echo $arrStatus["msg"];
    }
}
```